# Is there a way to have a nested for loop without having to create a new variable in locals?

Tags: terraform

On terraform v0.14.4

My variable looks like this:

```
variable "my_config" {
  type = object({
    instances = set(string)
    locations = set(string)
  })
  default = {
    locations = [
      "us",
      "asia"
    ]
    instances = [
      "instance1",
      "instance2"
    ]
  }
```

I want to loop over this var in a resource and create an instance of the resource for each location + instance. The "name" field of the resource will be `"<LOCATION>_<INSTANCE>"` as well.

I could create a new var in locals that reads the my_config var and generates a new var that looks like this:

```
[
  "us_instance1",
  "us_instance2",
  "asia_instance1",
  "asia_instance2",
]
```

I would prefer to not generate a new terraform var from this existing var though. Is it possible in a foreach loop to aggregate these two lists directly in a resource definition? Or is the only way to create a new data structure in locals?

## EDIT

I cannot get the flatten example in answer provided to work inside a resource definition. I get this error: `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.` This error happens if the type is `set(string)` or `list(string)`.

```
# This works
output "test" {
  value = flatten(
    [
      for location in var.my_config.locations : [
        for instance in var.my_config.instances : "${location}_${instance}"
      ]
    ]
  )
}

# This throws the error
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = flatten(
    [
      for location in var.my_config.locations : [
        for instance in var.my_config.instances : "${location}_${instance}"
      ]
    ]
  )
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the return value of:

```
[
  "us_instance1",
  "us_instance2",
  "asia_instance1",
  "asia_instance2",
]
```

with the input of the variable `my_config`, you could:

```
flatten([for location in var.my_config.locations : [
  for instance in var.my_config.instances : "${location}_${instance}"
]])
```

Whether or not you define this in a `locals` block is up to you. If you plan on re-using this value multiple times, then it would be more efficient to define it as a `local`. If you plan on on only using it once, then it would certainly make more sense to not define it in `locals`.

Note this also assumes `my_config` type is `object(list(string))`. The type was not given in the question, but if the type were otherwise then the code becomes much more obfuscated.

For the additional question about using this value as a `for_each` meta-argument value at the resource scope, it would need to be converted to type `set(string)`. This can be done easily with the `toset` function:

```
resource "resource" "this" {
  for_each = toset(<expression above or variable with return value of above assigned to it>)
}
```

Comment: How would this look in a resource definition? Sorry maybe I'm being dense, but I would be setting `for_each` in the resource to this flatten() expression?

Comment: When I try to use this with for_each I get this error: `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.`

Comment: I updated my question. I was using `set(string)`, but it does not work with `list(string)` either.

Comment: @red888 With the new question about using this as a `for_each` meta-argument value at the resource scope, I can update the answer for the additional question.

Comment: OK guess I should have specified, but that is what I meant by `directly in a resource definition`. How else would that be possible without a for loop inside a resource?

Comment: @red888 As stated in my comment above, I have updated the answer for the additional question. If it does not work for you, then please feel free to update with more necessary information.